# Spring boot with ElasticsearchRepository and RestHighLevelClient parameters query

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

I'm using Spring Boot with `ElasticsearchRepository` and `RestHighLevelClient`. I have this query in `mt` repository class:

```
public interface BillingCycleRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<BillingCycle, String> {
    List<BillingCycle> findByUserIdOrderByStartDateDesc(String userId);
}
```

In my console, I can see this:

```
org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient      : request [POST http://localhost:9200/dev-billing-cycle/_doc/_search?rest_total_hits_as_int=true&typed_keys=true&ignore_unavailable=false&expand_wildcards=open&allow_no_indices=true&ignore_throttled=true&search_type=query_then_fetch&batched_reduce_size=512]
```

It generates a lot of parameters, like `rest_total_hits_as_int` and `typed_keys.

Is it possible to configure these parameters and add any others, like `"filter_path", "preference"`?

Comment: these request are created by Elasticsearch's RestHighLevelClient. So for what requests are these parameters that you need? I can't find _filter_path_ in the Elasticsearch documentation

Comment: I'd like to do the same request that I did with my local elasticsearch:
http://localhost:9200/dev-billing-cycle/_doc/_search?preference=xyzabc123&filter_path= hits.hits._id,hits.hits._source

But using my spring query above.